# error when run script trough npm run, but didn't when run directly

Tags: reactjs, npm, lint

Im getting strange error when running lint script on my react js project

```
npm run lint
```

it gave me an error

```
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

but when I run the script directly on the terminal

```
./node_modules/.bin/eslint src --ext .ts,.tsx
```

there's no error

```
16 problems (0 errors, 16 warnings)
```

this is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "g-frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot",
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint src --ext .ts,.tsx",
    "ts-build": "tsc --noEmit --project tsconfig.json"
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
}
```

npm version : 8.1.2

does anyone ever encounter same problem or have a solution?

Comment: What do you use as the terminal? Must be gitbash or something like? This command is not a valid command for Windows command processor (cmd.exe). That's why it doesn't work from **package.json** -- npm must be using the default Windows "shell" to run the scripts. You need to change the command to `node_modules\.bin\eslint src --ext .ts,.tsx` in **package.json**

Comment: Yes, I use git bash terminal actually. that's why it run without error when I do the command `./node_modules/.bin/eslint src --ext .ts,.tsx`. but did not when trough `npm run lint`. Tried to change to `node_modules\.bin\eslint src --ext .ts,.tsx` in package.json but it gaves me an error `Invalid escape character in string.json(261)`

Comment: Ah, yes, my bad. Of course you need to escape backslashes in JSON! Use `node_modules\\.bin\\eslint src --ext .ts,.tsx`

Comment: @tromgy ah nice, this actually work, thanks.

Comment: wondering if this is because I just reinstalled my PC using windows 11, this didn't happen before in windows 10